# ShellExecute not opening page on Windows 8 when chrome is the default browser

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome

I have an elevated desktop application that sometimes opens webpages on errors. The problem I am having is on Windows 8 when Chrome is set as the default browser. It does not open the page, running the process non elevated works fine... Here is how I'm opening the page:

`ShellExecute( NULL, TEXT("open"),sPageURL,NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );`

where sPageURL is the url of the page.

I also tried opening an elevated CMD and opening a web page such as google.com through it like so:

`start http://www.google.com`

I got the error `"Class not registered"`.

What is the best alternative way to overcome this issue?

Comment: I remember an [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054548/shellexecute-fails-if-run-from-elevated-process-and-non-default-browser-set-in-w#comment16130396_12054548) because it sounded like an issue with Windows, but it might be a problem with the browser's registration.  Either way, I'm not sure how you can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are running Google in Windows 8 "App" mode rather than in "Desktop" mode.

It will even crash google chrome because file explorer is open in elevated mode. (no idea why though).

Best,

Comment: No, thats not the case sadly